# Is it possible to set jwt to optional during runtime?

Tags: flask, jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I am using Flask-JWT-Extended (https://pypi.org/project/Flask-JWT-Extended/) to secure my flask app. The `jwt_required` decorator takes `optional` as an argument. Nevertheless my flask app is created inside a class and I cannot set the `optional` argument before instantiating the class.
Here is what I tried:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, JWTManager

jwt_optional = False


class Node:

    def __init__(self, name: str, key: str, jwt_opt: bool = False):
        self.app = Flask(name)
        self.app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = key
        global jwt_optional
        jwt_optional = jwt_opt
        self.app.add_url_rule(rule='/get_token',
                              endpoint='get_token',
                              view_func=self.get_token,
                              methods=['GET'])

    @jwt_required(optional=jwt_optional)
    def get_token(self):
        print('Token success')
        return jsonify({'msg': 'Token success'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    node = Node('Test Node', key='unsafe', jwt_opt=True)
    app = node.app
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    jwt = JWTManager(app=app)
    test_app = app.test_client()
    response = test_app.get('/get_token')
    print(response.json)
```

I guess it's obvious that it does not work since the decorator is evaluated before I change the global variable.

Is it possible to make the token optional at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had to deal with the case of optional JWTs. What I ended up doing is putting the decorator on top of a generic function and then simply call that function during the route itself - or skip it, in case jwt_optional is True

```
jwt_optional = True

@jwt_required()
def jwt_protection():
   pass

# ...

class Node:
  # ...
  def get_token(self):
    if jwt_optional is False:
        jwt_protection()
    print('Token success')
    return jsonify({'msg': 'Token success'})
```

I thought this was a simple workaround, it might also help in your situation

Comment: No need for that, just use verify_jwt_in_request() https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/#flask_jwt_extended.verify_jwt_in_request. That’s all the jwt_required() decorator is calling.

Comment: thanks! Whats the recommended way to do this for flask_jwt? I'm getting a "Access to protected member warning" if I do this with the _jwt_required function, so I kept using the decorator. I see this works fine for flask_jwt_extended tho.

Comment: You are right, this will work. Nevertheless I thought I could still utilize the 'beauty' of a decorator and not change each function that needs the token. Since the jwt package already makes use of global app settings like the `JWT_SECRET_KEY` it might be useful to have a `JWT_OPTIONAL` value in the app config. I thought I might miss something like that but it would be a feature request to the developer.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 migrate away from flask jwt :) it’s been abandoned for years now

Comment: @Sebastian again no reason to put that in flask-jwt-extended. Just use some global config, say something in the flask config, to toggle that flag, and call verify_jwt_in_request(optional=<your_boolean_value>)